# Query with regard to nvl and case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

1.

```
select   case 
        when  id is null then name='muthu'
        end 
from muthu;
```

after executing this query am getting ORA-00905: missing keyword

> 905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" error.

2.

```
select nvl(id,"not found")  name from muthu;
```

> ORA-00904: "not found": invalid identifier

(oracle 10g db and sql developer 4.1.)
please can anyone let me know the latest version of sql developer

Comment: The question is about the errors or the latest version of sql developer? Also, what's wrong with the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?category=database&q=&product=)?

Comment: Please show us sample data and what you are trying to achieve as this isn't clear right now.

Comment: am having a table with two columns id and name. I want to write a query for checking id column for null values and update corresponding name as 'n/a'.

Comment: check, update, ... it's still not clear to me. Try to post some sample data and what you need to get with a select or the way you want to modify data if you need an update. Also, again, what is the question on sql developer about? Are you asking us what is the latest version of sql developer?

Comment: select nvl(id,null) from muthu;  its working correctly now, what mistake I was doing was I was trying to insert string into number column , because of that it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query fails because a boolean expression is not a *value*.  I think you want:

```
select (case when id is null then 'muthu'
        end) as name
from muthu;
```

The second fails because strings should be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.  So this should be:

```
select nvl(id, 'not found') as name
from muthu;
```

Although I prefer the ANSI-standard `coalesce()` to the database-specific `NVL()`.

If `id` is not a string, then you have to cast it to a string:

```
select nvl(cast(id as varchar2(255)), 'not found') as name
from muthu;
```

Comment: select nvl(id,'not found')as name from muthu; ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: select nvl(id,null) from muthu;
select   case 
            when id is null  then 17
            else id
         end 
from muthu; both queries are working correctly now. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the question, I assume **why?**

First query - I think you wanted to name this column `name` ? If so, at the end of the calculations or whatever on a column comes the naming:

```
select case when id is null then 'muthu'
    end as name
from muthu;
```

Second one - strings should be wrapped with single quotes, double quotes are for column names :

```
select nvl(id,'not found') as name
from muthu;
```

Comment: for 1st query I want validate id column for null, can you let me know how to do. am facing the same error.

Comment: and for second query even though I remove alas name am getting same error

Comment: select nvl(id,null) from muthu;
select   case 
            when id is null  then 17
            else id
         end 
from muthu;   both queries are working correctly now. thanks all.